# setup oracle 11g in integration of jsf spring hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc, oracle11g

i want to use oracle 11g in my project. i use maven,hibernate,spring and jsf.
but something is wrong. i have error.
my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- Beans Declaration -->
 <bean id="customer" class="model.Customer"/>

<!-- CustomerBo Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerBoImpl" class="bo.CustomerBoImpl">
      <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="CustomerDaoImpl" />
     </bean>


 <!-- Customer DAO Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerDaoImpl" class="dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
 <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@Mohsen-PC:1521:mydb" />
  <property name="user" value="system" />
  <property name="password" value="123" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
 <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>model.Customer</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

 <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

errors:

```
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '\n' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:303)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:209)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.ensureDriverLoaded(DriverManagerDataSource.java:101)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:133)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

Jul 01, 2012 6:24:11 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:11 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:12 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge15w8oijg1pn1qekqmy|7116eed7, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge15w8oijg1pn1qekqmy|7116eed7, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@Mohsen-PC:1521:mydb, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:12 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4247 ms
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:12 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.3 (FCS b03) for context '/SAMPLE'
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:14 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:14 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/SAMPLE/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Mohsen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\docs
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Mohsen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\examples
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@2d756ee7')
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Mohsen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\host-manager
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Mohsen\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\manager
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-7080"]
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15043 ms
Jul 01, 2012 6:24:34 PM com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl processAction
SEVERE: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:18)
    at bo.CustomerBoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerBoImpl.java:23)
    at managedbean.Customermanagedbean.addCustomer(Customermanagedbean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more

Jul 01, 2012 6:24:34 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
javax.faces.FacesException: #{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:881)
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:18)
    at bo.CustomerBoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerBoImpl.java:23)
    at managedbean.Customermanagedbean.addCustomer(Customermanagedbean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more
```

i added the ojdbc6 and c3p0 jars in lib of web-inf and maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an Oracle bug (#6362104). See the following pages:

- [OTN Discussion Forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=549705&tstart=-1)
- [Robert Stupp Blog](http://www.robert-stupp.de/blog/2008/01/oracle_malicious_11g_data_source_implementation.html)
- [The Reason behind Oracle 11g](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/the-reason-behind-oracle-11g-severe-error-while-registering-oracle-jdbc-diagnosability-mbean/)

It should be fixed in the latest version of *ojdbc6.jar* (Oracle 11g R2) and there are patched versions available from Oracle. Your version seems to be a very early version of *ojdbc6.jar*.

Comment: i install the lastest version of ojdbc6.jar, but it isnot solved.

Comment: ojdbc6.jar usually goes into a server directory shared by all applications, not into WEB-INF. Are you sure there isn't an older version in a shared directory?